# snv + http protocols with SElinux

Tags: apache-2.4, svn, selinux, svnserve

I was asked to run the subversion with http and svn protocols on CentOS 7 os. Installed apache and subversion. The issue arises when apache and subversion are to access the repository. Apache works with settings:

```
#ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 repository
```

But in this case the svnserve can not access it. Svnserve works after setting `#chcon -R -t svnserve_content_t /var/www/repository`. But in this case http protocol (apache) is blocked by SELinux.

I found similar problem here: [How do I get SELinux to allow Apache and Samba on the same folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/131105/how-do-i-get-selinux-to-allow-apache-and-samba-on-the-same-folder). But after more reading I chose the procedure described in [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01) and created a custom SELinux policy.

The policy looks like:

```
module my_svnserve 1.0;

require {
    type proc_t;
    type passwd_file_t;
    type httpd_sys_rw_content_t;
    type shell_exec_t;
    type random_device_t;
    type svnserve_t;
    type http_port_t;
    type bin_t;
    class capability { fsetid dac_override };
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
    class chr_file getattr;
    class dir { search read create write getattr rmdir remove_name open add_name };
    class file { rename read lock execute_no_trans ioctl unlink open append execute setattr create write getattr };
}

#============= svnserve_t ==============
allow svnserve_t bin_t:file { execute execute_no_trans };
allow svnserve_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow svnserve_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:dir { search read create write getattr rmdir remove_name open add_name };
allow svnserve_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:file { rename execute setattr read lock create getattr execute_no_trans write ioctl unlink open append };
allow svnserve_t passwd_file_t:file getattr;
allow svnserve_t passwd_file_t:file { read open };
allow svnserve_t proc_t:file getattr;
allow svnserve_t proc_t:file { read open };
allow svnserve_t random_device_t:chr_file getattr;
allow svnserve_t self:capability { fsetid dac_override };
allow svnserve_t shell_exec_t:file execute_no_trans;
allow svnserve_t shell_exec_t:file execute;
```

(it also consider svn hooks that connect to JIRA)

The question is: is this the right thing to do? Would it be better to create a new label and make custom policy for it? Or is using SELinux booleans better way?