# SELinux: How to allow apache, samba and tomcat access on the same file

Tags: httpd, selinux, tomcat7

Running RedHat 7.4

Until recently I could use

```
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t '/var/www(/.*)?'
restorecon -R /var/www
```

from answer https://serverfault.com/a/346779/125461
on [How do I get SELinux to allow Apache and Samba on the same folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/131105/how-do-i-get-selinux-to-allow-apache-and-samba-on-the-same-folder).

but public_content_rw_t no longer works for tomcat (tomcat-7.0.76-2.el7.noarch)

I managed to get past the issue by using

```
semanage permissive -a tomcat_t
```

but I'm looking for a context that allows tomcat & httpd to read and samba to read and write, or a context that allows rw to tomcat, httpd & samba.

Alternatively, is it possible to change the context tomcat uses to the httpd context ?