# Configure CentOS to allow executables to create and write files in dedicated directory

Tags: centos, web-server, selinux

I have a web app that receives, stores, and processes files using AI algorithms implemented in Python. The web app is developed in server-side scripting language, but when invoking the Python programs on uploaded files, SELinux denies permissions to access those files.

Suppose I have a site distribution package in the following directory format:

```
/bin    # Python binaries
/doc    # explains some important things
/web    # document root.
```

and a file pool directory in the environmnet variable `$FILE_POOL`

How do I correctly and safely configure SELinux to allow such access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One](https://serverfault.com/q/131105/493141) of the many popular search results suggests using `public_rw_content_t` for the file pool directory, but that's not correct under this scenario as it only applies to making Samba-shared files available for access to website executable scripts.

The correct way is to configure the directories for scripts (`/bin`) as `httpd_sys_script_exec_t` and then the file pool (`$FILE_POOL`) to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`. These are the dedicated filesystem context types for executable scripts and "file pools".

Reference: httpd_selinux man page at [man.freebsd.org](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=httpd_selinux&apropos=0&manpath=CentOS+7.1&arch=default&format=html)
, [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux) , and [redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-types)